# Does $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2^k}x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

Let $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2^k}x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Does this series converge absolutely?

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2^k}x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}$$ converges absolutely if $$\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^{2^k}x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}\right|=\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{|x|^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}$$ converges.

I guess that it depends on $x$ if this converges or not. For $x\in [-1,1]$ by the ratio test.
However, I'm not sure about the other $x$. How to proceed further?

Comment: What ratio do you get when $x>1$?

Comment: Since $(-1)^{2^k}=1$ for all considered $k$, we don't need to include that factor in the term; but absolute convergence hinges on what happens if we replace $x$ with $|x|$. As other answers have noted, all $x$ give absolute convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't depend on $x$. It always converges absolutely. Note that, if $x\neq0$,$$\frac{\frac{|x|^{2k+2}}{(2k+5)!}}{\frac{|x|^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}}=\frac{|x|^2}{(2k+5)(2k+4)}\to0.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \dfrac {x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!} \lt$

$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \lt$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{|x|^k}{k!} =e^{|x|}.$

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the absolute  partial sums are mon. increasing and bounded above by $e^{|x|},$

hence convergent for $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes since $$\sinh x = \sum\limits_{k=
0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

then $$  \sum\limits_{k=
2}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}\le  \sum\limits_{k=
2}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}= -1-\frac{x^2}{6}+ \sum\limits_{k=
0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\\=-1- \frac{x^2}{6}+ \frac{1}{|x|}\sum\limits_{k=
0}^\infty\frac{|x|^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}= =-1- \frac{x^2}{6}+ \frac{|\sinh x|}{|x|} $$

Comment: Why do you use an inequality rather than simply stating that $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2^k}x^{2k}}{(2k+3)!}=\frac1{x^3}\left(-x-\frac{x^3}6-\frac{x^5}{120}+\sinh x\right)$$ ? And besides, you have the wrong denominator for your $O(x^2)$ term.

Comment: @user5713492 the convergence is absolute